# Force composer to download git repo instead of zip

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I have some problem with composer.

```
 "require": {
        "php":                ">=5.3.2",
        "kriswallsmith/buzz": "0.7"
    },
```

Repo https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/tree/v0.7

Unfortunately github returns 502 for this request https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/zipball/v0.7

Request URL:https://nodeload.github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/zipball/v0.7
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway

Luckily git clone still works ;)

Is it possible to tell/ask composer to user git clone instead of downloading zipball for this one dependency?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quickest solution is to run `install` or `update` with the option `--prefer-source`

```
php composer.phar install --prefer-source
```

In this way git clone will be used for **all** dependencies, I don't know if there's a setting  to limit to one dependency only.

Comment: In `composer.json` it seems you should be able to enforce this, via

`{
...
    "type": "project",
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "source"
    },
...
}
`

but in my experience that seems to get ignored.  So the above command appears to be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [preferred-install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install) order matters. I've tested on `Composer version 1.8.3 2019-01-30 08:31:33`

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "drupal/external_entities": "source",
        "*": "dist"
    }
}
```

Next ran

```
composer require drupal/external_entities
```

and the git repo appeared.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way than prefer source, you can set repository with type 'VCS' it means that that package will be search in your VCS for example GIT instead of packagist

your **composer.json**

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "kriswallsmith/buzz": "dev-0.17.x"
    }
}
```

[More info here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Comment: Testing this in July 2020, looks like this will only download a copy of the repository, but not do a 'git clone' on it.  The implication is that this is fine for using the code, but not for modifying and contributing back to the repository.

Comment: Of course, it'll do it. If you want to modify the code you can create PR in the main repository or you can fork the project and use it as you wish.