# Force composer.json to export vendor repositories instead of cloning

Tags: php, git, symfony

I am using Symfony2 for PHP Development and it is awesome framework.

I am using it now for making solid template for making my new web - applications. (A company framework built on top of symfony2).

I got a problem with vendor libraries. I am using git for hosting my project, and, when I enter dependencies in composer.json and call update, it clone whole repositories, with whole history of every library. Even worse, those repositories are subrepositories to my main repository, and files in those libraries won't commit. After trying to clone project on another computer it won't work because of lack of vendor libraries. I just want to force composer to export contents of the repositories instead of cloning it. I want pure files, not the repository.

I am of course can using composer.json forever, but I want to make my boilerplate functional, even if github will stop work. And another reason, that I am editing this project from two separate machines, and I need all my files in project in repository, calling 2 times per day composer.json update and waiting 5 minutes every time is not funny.

Comment: It's not recommended to commit /vendors folder. If you add a submodule, you won't commit files, but only the reference to the commit. Same for svn:externals.

Comment: And this is exactly what I don't want to do. I want pure copy insteead of repository or reference, no matter of consequences.

How to force composer to do that? maybe some option on git will help me with this?

Comment: Have you checked this part of the doc: http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md ?

Comment: You can use `--prefere-source` when running composer which forces composer to download the dependencies and extract them instead of using git. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173973/force-composer-to-download-git-repo-instead-of-zip

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably the `--prefer-dist` option which will download a zip (when available) instead of repository, which you can then commit.

Answer (score 0):

Within your repository, you're committing composer.json file that will tell the composer install needed dependencies. There is no need to commit vendor/* folder and enlarge your repository size. The cleaner way: All the developers that checkout your repository should run composer update to download missing files. And your deploy scripts should run a composer update after deploying.

Please read: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md